# Two circles with "exponential decay" coloring, and alpha < 1, have trouble with color mixing?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to get circles such that their coloring is radially symmetric, with center being the darkest, and exponential decay in color as one moves farther away from the center along the radius, I used `imshow` with `clip_path`s using `Circle` patches.

Here's a toy script that overlaps two such circles: https://gist.github.com/bmer/7063cc2dd09f1b80a252

Here's the output of the script:

[image]

As you can see, even though the `alpha` is set at 0.5 for both clipped images, there doesn't seem to be proper "color mixing" occurring (we should see a result that is symmetric along the x-axis).

Why is that, and what could I do to fix this issue?